# focus on session variable in php

Tags: php, focus, session-variables

How to set focus on the 'name' variable? The following code is not working

```
if(empty($_SESSION['name']))
{       
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('name').focus();</script>        
    $_SESSION['nameErr'] = "Please enter name";     
    $_SESSION['result'] = false;
    //form page location
    header('location:stu_form.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want the input box get highlighted or get focused when I click the submit button on form.

Answer (score 0):

Set focus is done on an HTML elements and not on Php variables.

If you put the name in some html input element you can do this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
?>
 <input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

And then from the Javascript make it focused:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('name').focus();</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['name']))
{       
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('name').focus();</script>";        
    $_SESSION['nameErr'] = "Please enter name";     
    $_SESSION['result'] = false;
    //form page location
    header('location:stu_form.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: *look* at the code. Does that look like it's going to produce anything useful? The session will echo the script which will perform a focus and then it will set the session and then it will redirect. what's the point? The redirect will just kill the javascript focus.